# I want to output the result of a file using echo in Unix / Linux #QueueManager

Tags: io-redirection, echo

A: runmqsc QueueManager < Input1

I want to output the result of A in a file. Input1 contains multiple codes that will be run in QueueManager.

My command is:

```
echo "runmqsc QueueManager < Input1" > OutputResult
```

but above is only outputting "runmqsc QueueManager < Input1" not the actual result. How can do this using echo command?

I'll be needing to have a logic like below but I don't know in Unix command.

A = runmqsc QueueManager < Input1

A > OutputResult

Comment: I don't really understand the question here. Do you want to store the commands in a variable, and then later on run those and redirect the output? Or just redirect input and output simultaneously

Comment: I also don't understand what you're wanting to do. Please step back from pseudo-code and explain what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You want to capture the output of a program. That's simply...

```
unmqsc QueueManager <Input1 >OutputResult
```

If want the output sent back to your terminal *and* be captured, that's different. You want to send the output to 2 different places. You could read from the file as it is being written....

```
unmqsc QueueManager <Input1 >OutputResult &
tail -f OutputResult
```

however the 'tail' command will not exit when unmqsc exits and closes OutputResult. Also there's a chance that some of the output will not be sent to your terminal.

I would use....

```
unmqsc QueueManager <Input1 | tee OutputResult
```

(The `tee` command copies its input to 2 output streams).